# Sequential number obfusication for puzzle site

Tags: php, encryption

I'm working on a site that generates a random puzzle and the exact puzzle can be recreated using this number. So i give them the url to the puzzle in case they want to share it with a friend or solve it later etc.  somepuzzlesite.com/4233312409408127365 would generate a unique puzzle that is always the same if they use that link/number

What I don't want is to expose how the puzzle is generated. The 9th digit, for example, can be 0 to 3, and defines the rotation of the puzzle.

If I just use it "as is" then a user could change a single digit in the url, see what changes, and eventually discover how I make my puzzle. I also wouldn't mind if my number were smaller, since I don't need all the way to 9:

digits 1st to 8th [possible values 0 to 5]

digit 9 [value 0 to 3]

digits 11th to 20th represent the arrangement of 10 objects in order.
I could just specify the first 9 objects in order, and then the unmentioned item is assumed to be last. (that gets me down to 9 digits used)

I could change the base, or use alpha characters in my URL in addition to digits, but some alpha characters are always trouble - lowercase "L" and "1" get mixed up easily, and "o" and zero can too.

But to keep the question simple, I'd just like to make it so that changing a single digit would represent a totally different number, and thereby create a totally different puzzle, rather than the minor difference that would result if I only changed one factor.

Comment: Not sure if this is a viable/sensible option for your scenario, but have you considered maintaining a database of all puzzles that you've ever generated, and assigning each one a unique incrementing ID?  That way, you have a completely obfuscated one-to-one map between a unique ID and the "puzzle-generation" string.

Comment: You could also use a simple cipher on the URL number

Comment: @Lee: You'd need more than a character-by-character cipher though, as the OP says "changing a single digit would represent a totally different number".  So the question is: what cipher?

Comment: Note: There are 18,284,971,622,400 possible combinations, which fits into 40 bits. You can't go below that. In base64 it would be 8 characters; in hex that's 10 characters.

Comment: @Vilx weird, in my calculator the number 18,284,971,622,400 is 90 bits...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's `10000 10100001 01001101 00111101 00000000 00000000` in binary, which is 45 bits. OK, so I did miscount by 5. That's still not 90 bits. (And, for the note, 8 chars in base64 and 12 chars in hex)

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone; I am working on grouping all same-max digits together, then setting that as the base for that group of digits. So if I have digits 1 to 8 that can be 0 to 5, I group those like 012345012 and then convert that from base 6 to base 10.  That seems the most economical way to exactly use the bits I need. Because the size can change, I either need to pad leading zeros or use a break character so I can find my "base 6 section" again and add water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see... a rather naive approach would be this: Assign each value so many bits as is necessary to hold it. That is, you'd have eight 3-bit values, one 2-bit value, and ten 4-bit values. That's 8*3+2+10*4=66 bits. Well, if you skip that last one, you'll get 62 bits. You can get it even smaller, but that gets unnecessarily complicated.

Anyway.

Just take any standard encryption algorithm and apply it to these 62 bits. The industry-standard [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) (aka Rijndael) operates on 128-bit blocks, which might be a bit too lengthy - or maybe not, depending on your preferences. [3DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) won't be any worse for your purposes, and works on 64-bit blocks, which is just perfect.

When you've got your encrypted 64 or 128 bits, just hex-encode them and make that the URL. If it's 64 bits, you'll have 16 hex characters. Not too much. And you'd be hard pressed to go lower anyway. Plus, it uses only 0-9, A-F, and there is little chance of mix-ups when calling over the phone. Not that people often share links vocally these days. :P

Comment: Yeah, we got the same idea I guess. Hopefully I explained slightly better :)

Comment: This is one those cases where ECB is correct mode to use for the block cipher.

Comment: If you don't have an Initialization Vector, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Your number is about 18 digits or about 61-62 bits in size. That means that it will fit nicely in a single DES block (8 bytes, or 64 bits). If you encrypt it in ECB mode you would retrieve a 64 bit value, which looks like a random value. You can leave the key on the server. A single 8 byte DES key should be enough for obfuscation, but you could also use 16/24 byte key for DESede encryption.

So: when generating a new random puzzle: create your number, convert it into a byte array with a length of 8 bytes (or N * 8 bytes if your number gets too big) then encrypt it with a single key kept on the server (8, 16 or 24 randomly generated bytes) and on some backup. The result will be 8 bytes again, which you can convert to a number of about 20 digits. If the user supplies a previously generated number, you can decrypt it with the key on the server, revert the resulting bytes back into the number used to create the puzzle.

Note that if the user just enters some random number, it will still decrypt, so you may want to check the resulting number for validity (e.g. test if a digit is indeed 0..3 and not something else).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to solve this would be to save the puzzles internally and bind the puzzle to an unique ID.

Comment: Hi Zar, welcome to stackoverflow and thanks for the answer! One problem with your solution is that the table may get a bit large. 19 digits is a rather large number of digits, and even if they cannot have every possible value, the number of possible ID's will still grow exponentially, and they all need to store the 19 digit number as well.